# Static files not working, using jinja in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner using Flask. My static files don't working, the root 
I've this tree directories :

```
/          <-------------- launching (flask run) the site, here.
/static
/static/css
/static/js
/static/img
/flask_mysite
/flask_mysite/log
/flask_mysite/templates
```

The flask app variable :

```
$ echo $FLASK_APP
flask_mysite/__init__.py
```

To navigate **in the root `/` folder**, using an vagrant VM :

```
flask run --host=192.168.56.101
```

In the */flask_mysite/__init.py__* I've the jinjia config :

```
flask_mysite.jinja_env.globals['static'] = (
    lambda filename: url_for('static', filename=filename)
)

from flask_mysiteimport views, models

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_mysite.run(debug=True)
```

And, in the */flask_mysite/templates/base.html*, for example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static('css/main.css') }}">
```

And so, the html generated :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/main.css">
```

Can anobody can help me please ? :)

Thanks.
Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong the static files: http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/favicon.ico') }}">
```

This is the code that Flask documentation uses for static files, the way are you using it seems to be the Django way

EDIT:

Your flaskapp.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
return render('template.html')
```

Your template.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="{{ urlfor('static' , filename='css/yourcss.css'}}">
    <script src="{{ urlfor('static' , filename='js/yourjs.js'}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- the rest of your html -->
</body>
</html>
```

Assuming that you have "static/css/yourcss.css" and "static/js/yourjs.js" and the .py file is in the root of the folder with the static folder

Comment: Thanks. But, in production, it's working like it is (with apache virtual host). But, il local mode, with a VM, don't. If I move the 'static' folder in 'flask_mysite/static'. It's ok :).

Comment: In production maybe your alias for "/static" could be your static folder, in local if you are using Apache too you should replicate the same config, or use the Flask way to serve static files

Comment: And, I move the "static" folder without change the code like you told me. #update : No, in local mode, I'm using neither apache or nginx, just the command line (flask run)

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#static-files

Quoting the official documentation:
Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where the CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can do that as well. Just create a folder called static in your package or next to your module and it will be available at /static on the application.

To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint name:

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've already read the documentation :). But I'm using jinja globals. So, I think, like you said, that apache serve the static files too.

Comment: If you serve your static folder from Apache, you could avoid using the Flask/Jinja way to serve your static files, but if you don't use Apache in local running Flask you will need to serve it serving as the Flask way, or run apache in your local server and create a static folder in the document root "/var/www/html/static" (if you are running Apache in Debian/Ubuntu), there are many ways to do it, these two are the faster ways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156561/discussion-between-fabrice-and-jason-jimenez).